# Interpretation of coefficients from multinomial logistic regression

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, multinomial-distribution, multinomial-logit

I have run a multinomial logistic regression model with a four level response variable (walk, bike, bus and car) and two predictor variables being their gender (female/male) and where they live (urban/rural), and I'm struggling with the interpretation of the coefficients in regards of the intercept.

I have two questions:

1) I interpret the intercept to be for females living in urban areas -> Is this correct? - So, from the output I read that urban females are less likely to walk then to take the car.

2) When interpreting the coefficients for gender and where they live, do I add the logit to the intercept value?

E.g. Is it right to say "males are more likely to walk than females, but still they are more likely to take the car then to walk overall(because -0.7643 + 0.4 are still negative)" or "males are more likely to walk than to take the car then females, and males are overall more likely to walk then to take the car (because the logit (0.4) is positive)"?

The coefficient estimates from the model output looks like this (reference = car):

**Variable Estimate**

Intercept:walk -0.7643

Sex(Male):walk 0.4

Live(Rural):walk 0.0559

Intercept:bike -1.9524

Sex(Male):bike 0.6747

Live(Rural):bike 0.5863

Intercept:buss -1.1971

Sex(Male):buss 0.3912

Live(Rural):buss 0.7632

Appreciate all the help I can get!